# SCNetworkReachabilityFlags are 0 when the internet is plugged in

Tags: ios, objective-c

When monitoring the network status using `SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback` why are the SCNetworkReachabilityFlags 0 when I plug the internet in, and why don't they update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the iPhone simulator. If you connect the simulator to the internet by plugging an ethernet cable into your machine you will get this behaviour. However if you connect the simulator to the internet by turning your machines wifi on  will get two callbacks, the first one will still have the flags set to 0 but the second call back will have the flags set appropriately.